# Xpath - correctly combining multiple axes

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to learn how to correctly combine two xpath axes to locate a desired element, and having some problems that I hope someone can help with.

```
    <div A>
    <div A id="New Post Message"> 
    <div A>
        <div B>
        <div B>
           <a C>
           "Website:"
           <a C href="https://www.whatIwant.com/variable">
```

Using xpath: `//*[@id='New Post Message']/following::a[starts-with(@href, 'https://www.whatIwant.com')]`
What I want can be selected, but there are other similar links that I don't want that can get selected depending on how the post is submitted.

Using xpath: `//*[text()[contains(.,'Website:')]]/following::a[starts-with(@href, 'https://www.whatIwant.com')]`
The type of link is selected, but from the whole page and I only want the ones I haven't seen before.

From reading around I thought I could chain the two axes together to identify my desired element(s) with xpath: `//*[@id='New Post Message']/following::*[text()[contains(.,'Website:')]]/following::a[starts-with(@href, 'https://www.whatIwant.com')]`, but it doesn't select anything in this case.

Any guidance for what I'm doing wrong is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Found a typo in my combined and it seems to run now, but is still not as selective as I'd like since other links can be included after the "website:" tag.   Again, any suggestions more than welcome!

Comment: What element are you trying to locate here relatively to what element? The `<a C href="https://www.whatIwant.com/variable">` relatively to `<div A id="New Post Message">`?

Comment: Regarding this, "there are other similar links that I don't want that can get selected depending on how the post is submitted." This means there are matches in other parts of the HTML -- we can't diagnose that without actually *seeing* the HTML

Comment: @ Prophet - I'd like to find any link that is immediately after a "Website:" tag, but is also after the "New Post Message" divider.

Comment: @ C. Peck - All of the <a C> format will/can have links that get selected using the first xpath.  Whether the link I want is in the first <a C>, second, or third depends on how its posted.

Comment: While the `id="New Post Message"` is upper while both `Website` and `href="https://www.whatIwant.com/variable"` inside it and `href="https://www.whatIwant.com/variable"` comes after `Website` and these last two are siblings. Correct?

Comment: @ Prophet - I think the second part is correct.  Apologies if I'm misunderstanding you, but the <div A> that has the "new post message" banner is the preceding sibling of the <div A> that contains the href I'm searching for.  The site seems to use a "blank" temporary post to indicate new content below.   Then yes, the hyperlink that I want to see if always immediately preceded by the "Website:" tag